# Exporting HBase table to mysql

Tags: mysql, hbase, sqoop

I am using hbase-0.90.6. I want to export the data from HBase to mysql. I know two-step process , first by running a mapreduce job to pull Hbase data into flat files, then exports flat file data into mysql.

Is their any other tool which I can use to reduce this two-step to one. Or can we use sqoop to do the same in one step. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that Sqoop do not support exports directly from HBase at the moment. Sqoop can help you in the two-step process with the second step - e.g. Sqoop can take data from HDFS and export them to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sqoop is the tool that can be used for both importing as well as exporting ur data from/to mysql and HBase

You can know more about Sqoop @
http://sqoop.apache.org

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know that sqoop is used for importing and exporting. But my question was "can we export the data from HBase to mysql in 1 step". If you have any example or link then please do share. Thanks.