# How to export Hbase table to MySql table

Tags: mysql, hbase, sqoop

I am trying exporting Hbase table to mysql table using sqoop.

Following is my query:

```
> sqoop-export 
> --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver_ip:3306/mysqldb 
> --username user 
> --password pwd 
> --table mysqltbl 
> --update-key empid 
> --export-dir hostname:60030/hbase/tblfromhbase
```

> where hostname:60030 is my Hbase root dir path and port.

error coming to me are

```
> 1) ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException
> as:hbase (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException:Failed on local
> exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException:Protocol
> message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details :
> local host is: "hostname/ip";destination host is: "hostname":60030;
> 
> 2) ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job:
> java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception:
> com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException:Protocol message
> end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details :local host
> is: "hostname/ip"; destination host is: "hostname":60030;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes ..... and?!?!?? What's your **question** ??? Have you tried anything at all **yourself**?

Comment: I am trying following query:- sqoop-export --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver_ip:3306/mysqldb --username user --password pwd --table mysqltbl --update-key empid --export-dir  hostname:60030/hbase/tblfromhbase

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Ok sorry for that, i had formatted query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that Sqoop do not support exports directly from HBase at the moment. You can overcome this by firstly using mapreduce to export data from HDFS to normal files and subsequently calling Sqoop to export them to MySQL.

You can find additional information in question [12911042](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911042/exporting-hbase-table-to-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Exporting mysql table to hbase with sqoop is handy, but Exporting hbase table to mysql is not. This is an indirect way. Exporting hbase table to hive, create hive table, then dump to sql file, and import to mysql. Check it out: http://blog.csdn.net/zreodown/article/details/8850172